# Updating External system from excel

Tags: c#, excel, interop, office-interop

It's obviously possible from a demo i saw earlier but didn't catch enough details

I envision making a function call such as

```
=MyRTDReverse("keyvalue", "fieldName", [AC51])
```

or

```
=MyRTDReverse("keyvalue", [AB51], [AC51])  // where AB51 has the field name and AC51 has the field value
```

etc.

where updating the value in cell AC51 triggers a change

any samples/patterns on how this would work ?

Update - using .Net 3.5 + VSTO
UPDATE 2 - would prefer to not use VSTO and instead make a UDF/RTD like call routine

Comment: Are you using VSTO ? Which Version of .NET ?

Comment: Hi Kumar, Please see my question on the VSTO 2010 forum regarding creating User Defined Functions in C# : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevelopmentprerelease/thread/85edd66b-b778-4836-b706-fae8c4af442c You will find links there to the previous "standard" ways of going about defining a function in C# that can be used in a cell in a WorkSheet (and they're not pretty). The issue of monitoring a range for change is, however, very easy, and lots of sample code on SO for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger something based on a value change in a cell, handle the `Worksheet_Change` event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    'here, check whether Target, a Range, is one of your "trigger" cells,
    'and if it is, react accordingly
End Sub
```

To define a custom function:

```
Function MyFunction(Argument1, Argument2)
    'do stuff with your arguments, and set MyFunction equal to the return value
End Function
```

In a cell, you can then use the function like `= MyFunction("value", 3)`

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB controlling Excel : C# VSTO you have to do some real "hacking" to create UDF's (User Defined Functions) in C#, and use them on the WorkSheet. I have a question up on the VSTO 2010 beta forum right now about this : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officedevelopmentprerelease/thread/85edd66b-b778-4836-b706-fae8c4af442c I'd hoped this would be simpler in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, Office 2010 beta, etc. No response yet. I'd like to know in what context your example of defining a Function and calling it on a WorkSheet is created in : is this using VSTO ?

Comment: @BillW No, sorry, my response preceded the update, so I didn't piece the VSTO thing together -- my response is strictly within Excel, using VBA.

Comment: If you want to create Excel UDF's in .Net, you should have a look at [ExcelDna](http://exceldna.codeplex.com).